# Common Preg_replace for download and url links

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Right now i'm using

```
$content = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?/[\w/_\.%\-+~]+(\.exe|\.mp3|\.pdf|\.rar|\.doc|\.jar|\.ppt|\.xls|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.mp4|\.avi|\.mkv|\.flv|\.3gp|\.mms|\.sis|\.sisx|\.jad|\.mdi|\.qcp)(\?\S+)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">Download</a>', $content);
```

for download link replacement with Download.

and

```
$content = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?((/[\w/_\.%\-+~]*)?(\?\S+)?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $content);
```

for normal url link replacement which doesn't support # and many other special symbols.

But, i want to apply both this statement on the same text.

So, i want a common regex statment or a methodology which i can apply by which both url link and download link re placer can work on same text if any download link appears it replaces it with Download or if any url link comes it replaces with url link.

e.g. replace
http://www.abc.com/song1.mp3

http://www.exp.com/#p3+x2

http://www.youtube.com/

with

```
<a href="http://www.abc.com/song1.mp3" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a href="http://www.exp.com/#p3+x2" target="_blank">http://www.exp.com/#p3+x2</a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">http://www.youtube.com/</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
$urls = array(
    'http://www.abc.com/xxx/song1.mp3',
    'http://www.exp.com/yyy/#p3+x2',
    'http://www.youtube.com/zzz/'
);
foreach($urls as $url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    if (preg_match('~/$~', $parts['path'])) {
        echo "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>$url</a>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>Download</a>\n";
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
<a href='http://www.abc.com/xxx/song1.mp3' target='_blank'>Download</a>
<a href='http://www.exp.com/yyy/#p3+x2' target='_blank'>http://www.exp.com/yyy/#p3+x2</a>
<a href='http://www.youtube.com/zzz/' target='_blank'>http://www.youtube.com/zzz/</a>
```

Comment: wht happens if the text is something like this

" Download song from http://www.abc.com/xxx/song1.mp3
  and watch its video from http://www.youtube.com/y=43434q
  and for more details check http://www.songs.com?q=434343."

Comment: @SobhagyaMohanty: what result do you want these examples give? In the question, all examples begin with `http://`.

Comment: Sorry, I left http:// now
 
" Download song from http://www.abc.com/xxx/song1.mp3 and watch its video from http://www.youtube.com/y=43434q and for more details check http://www.songs.com?q=434343."